# Ember Component and Dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dependency-injection

I've got a simple initializer that injects a singleton class into views and components. When I use the component in a template like

```
{{component-name}}
```

I am then able to access the injected object from the component.

If I create an instance of the component from code:

```
comp = App.ComponentNameComponent.create()
```

the injected object is null.

Does injection only work on components added via a template? Is there something special I need to do to inject into components that I want to manage programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For dependency injection to work, you must look up the component from the container. Ember does this when you use a component in a template, but when you instantiate one directly that doesn't happen. So if you want that property injected, you should use the container like this:

```
comp = container.lookup('component:component-name');
```

Every object looked up by the Ember container (routes, controllers, views, etc) automatically has a `container` property added to it. So assuming you wanted to create an instance of a component in a controller, you would do this:

```
comp = this.get('container').lookup('component:component-name');
```

There's no public documentation for the container, so my suggestion would be to just [read the source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/container/lib/container.js).

Comment: ah, ok, that makes sense. lookup looks like it returns an instance. how do I pass parameters to the component using this method the way you can in a template?

Comment: nevermind, looks like lookupFactory will give me a reference to the registered component and I can use that to instantiate with options.

Answer (score 1):

Your component needs to be created by a container to have everything properly injected.

`var comp = this.container.lookup('component:component-name');`

Objects created by the container will have the `container` object automatically injected into it. In other words, code above will work only if the context object has been created by the container.